# How to implement ctrl click behavior to copy text from an embedded pdf in a webapp?

Tags: javascript, jsf, pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I have a requirement for a webapp to implement the following behavior:

After a webform is opened with an embedded PDF object is shown in the browser the user needs to be able to select a text in the document with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>mouse click</kbd> after which the selected text is copied to an inputfield in the same webform that the embedded PDF object is shown.

Are there API's out there (preferably open source) that implement this behavior? Can I meet this requirement using techniques like JSP, JSF, PrimeFaces, Javascript or HTML5 and how would I do that?

Comment: Checking for the control key during a click should be easy -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778621/how-to-check-if-control-key-is-pressed-while-mouse-click**

Comment: Sure. But how to copy the data from an embedded object in the onCtrlClick method?

Comment: I don't think adeneo's answer would work because you need it inside the PDF versus text on the page. @Martijn, can you make the assumption that every user would use Adobe Reader, or something?

Comment: [Missed the edit window] You can write javascript inside of acrobat, but I am not an expert in PDF JS, so you can browse [some tutorials](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/filter/search&keywords=form&channel=tutorials&category=+13&tut_type=Video+OnDemand+Infographic+HTML/) maybe?

Comment: @RyanB Yes, that assumption could work, I am going to look in the tutorials.

Comment: pdf-js could be an option too. http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example I'll use

- [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)
- JSF 2.2 (doesn't really matter what version, but it's better to be 2.x)
- PrimeFaces (for the inputField or textArea) * *optional*

*Steps:*

- Downloading and Integrating PDF.js
- Register Event on CTRL

### Downloading and Integrating PDF.js

[Download PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/archive/master.zip), after the download is complete unzip it, you would see the following folder hierarchy

```
.
 ├── LICENSE
 ├── build
 │   ├── pdf.js
 │   └── pdf.worker.js
 └── web
     ├── cmaps/
     ├── compatibility.js
     ├── compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf
     ├── debugger.js
     ├── images/
     ├── l10n.js
     ├── locale/
     ├── viewer.css
     ├── viewer.html
     └── viewer.js
```

Assuming you have a JSF project with a `resources` folder inside `webapp`, copy the following files from web folder (from the unziped file) into `resources` in which they would look like this :

**webapp/resources** folder

```
├── css
│   └── viewer.css (web/viewer.css)
├── images
│   └── pdfjs
│       ├── ** All the images inside (web/images)
└── js
   └── pdfjs
       ├── compatibility.js (web/compatibility.js)
       ├── l10n.js (web/l10n.js)
       ├── pdf.js (web/pdf.js)
       ├── pdf.worker.js (web/pdf.worker.js)
       └── viewer.js (web/viewer.js)
```

Edit **viewer.css** to resolve all the required images, replace each `url` with

`"#{resource['images/pdfjs/correspondingImageName']}"`

here's a full resolved [viewer.css](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/css/viewer.css)

Create xhtml file with the content of `viewer.html` (web/viewer.html from zip), which would represent the viewer markup, the reason that I'de use the viewer with all the html 5 markup is the ability to select text, not like the [canvas only example](http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-prevnext-v2/7334/edit#html,live)

Here's a full copied example of `viewer.html` into [viewer.xhml](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/pdfjs/viewer.xhtml)

Notice in the end I've included the libraries in the following order:

```xhtml
<h:outputScript name="js/pdfjs/compatibility.js" target="head" /> 
<h:outputScript name="js/pdfjs/l10n.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript name="js/pdfjs/pdf.js" target="head" />  
<h:outputScript name="js/pdfjs/viewer.js" target="head" />
```

To get `PDF.js` running you need to specify two things, the `pdf.worder.js` location and the `pdfURL` (see in [viewer.xhml](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/pdfjs/viewer.xhtml#L314))

```javascript
 <script>
     var DEFAULT_URL = "#{pdfURL}"; //pdf should be hosted on your domain name (ajaxly loaded) 
     PDFJS.workerSrc = "#{resource['js/pdfjs/pdf.worker.js']}";
 </script>
```

### Register Event on CTRL

Define an `inputText` or `inputTextArea`

```xhtml
<p:inputTextarea id="inputTextArea" />
```

Now register an event of keydown or whatever that fit, example:

```javascript
 $('.pdfZone').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == "17"){ // CTRL key
       $('#inputTextArea').text(window.getSelection().toString())
     }                 
 });
```

`.pdfZone` is a `div` container of the pdf `viewer`

You can find a full example on github [[1](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/pdfjs/viewer.xhtml#L314)] [[2](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/pdfjs/main.xhtml)], and **an online** [Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/pdfjs/main.xhtml).

Note: I didn't use CTRL + Click because in my Mac OSX would trigger the  Right Click, anyhow you could change the event handling.

*Suggestion to use CTRL + Click (but the demo would use only CTRL)*

```javascript
 $('.pdfZone').on('mouseup',function(e) {                       
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
       $('#inputTextArea').text(window.getSelection().toString());
     }
 });
```